# equality of value implies equality of stopping time

Tags: stopping-times

Question: Let X be a stochastic process and T a stopping time of ${\mathcal{F}^{X}_{t}}$. Suppose that for some pair $\omega$, $\omega$' $\in$ $\Omega$, we have $X_{t}(\omega)=X_{t}(\omega')$ for all t $\in [0,T(\omega)]\cap[0,\infty]$. Show that $T(\omega)=T({\omega}')$.

By definition, we have $\omega \in T^{-1}([0,T(\omega)])\subseteq \mathcal{F}^{X}_{T(\omega)}$. And my intuition gives that $\omega$' should belong to 
$T^{-1}([0,T(\omega)])$ since the value of process coincide on $[0,T(\omega)]$.Then, similar argument can be done to show the equality. Embarrassingly, I am not able to show it.
The gap is that if  $X_{t}(\omega)=X_{t}(\omega')$ for all t $\in [0,T]$, is there any element in ${\mathcal{F}^{X}_{T}}$ containing only one of them? If not, my approach would work.

Please help me fill in the gap if it is true. Or please provide a proof of the root problem.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by the notation $[0,T(\omega)]\cap[0,\infty]$. Isn't this just $[0,T(\omega)]$?

Comment: In the book, it is [0, +infinity)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** The collection $\cal C$ of subsets $A$ of $\Omega$ with $1_A(\omega)=1_A(\omega^\prime)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. If $X_s(\omega)=X_s(\omega^\prime)$ for some $s$, then $\sigma(X_s)\subseteq {\cal C}$. If $X_s(\omega)=X_s(\omega^\prime)$ for all $0\leq s\leq T$, then ${\cal F}_T\subseteq {\cal C}$.

Comment: How do you define $\mathcal-{F}_T$

Comment: In the last sentence $T$ refers to the real value $T(\omega)$, where $\omega$ is fixed, and $\mathcal F_t$ is the $\sigma$-field generated by $X$'s.